# Rails 3.1: What next - learning materials?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Just finished [Michael's Hartl online tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). So my current state is: a little bit of Ruby knowledge and some Rails, based on this tutorial. 
Where do I go from here?

1. I understand that Javascript is a must, but in Rails 3.1 it has been replaced with CoffeeScript. So which one should I choose to learn?
2. What would be the nex step in learning RoR?

Comment: Just keep reading, learning, and playing. You don't need a structured lesson plan. Also, accept more answers.

Comment: Take a look at this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails

Comment: @coreyward Thanks. Can I "accept comments" as well or only answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places you could go from here; these are just my opinions.

1. Think of something you want to try to build, and try to build it. In my opinion, this is one of the best ways to learn the framework--wrestle with it yourself, and figure out along the way what you're doing right and wrong, and what you understand and what you only think you understand. ;)
2. Check out [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com) and watch old episodes that sound interesting to you. Some of the older ones can be slightly out of date due to being for Rails 2, but Ryan has started re-releasing these in [RailsCasts Pro](http://railscasts.com/pro). There are also some really great "Intro to Rails Version (something)" and "Understand the New (whatever)" videos--[CoffeeScript is one such topic covered](http://railscasts.com/episodes/267-coffeescript-basics).
3. Check out some books that dig deeper into Rails if that's the way you learn. [The Rails 3 Way](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345) is one such book you may consider.
4. Consider reading the Rails source code to find out how something works. It can be complicated at times, but the rewards are worth it. Also check out the [Routing Walkthrough](http://railscasts.com/?search=Routing+Walkthrough&utf8=%E2%9C%93) RailsCasts to see how you might approach this.

[Edit] Regarding CoffeeScript: It's a nice language built *on top* of JavaScript, and is also completely optional in Rails 3. Personally, I'm a big fan of CS, and was before Rails decided to adopt it as a default, but if you don't like it just remote the CoffeeScript line from your `Gemfile` and name your stuff `whatever.js` instead of `whatever.js.coffee`.

Good luck, and have fun!

Comment: "Think of something you want to try to build, and try to build it." ------ Doing it right now :)